# TimerTask won't stop the process

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class HtmlParser {

    private final NetworkSettings networkSettings;

    private final Site site;
    public ConcurrentSkipListSet<String> getUrls(String url) {

        ConcurrentSkipListSet<String> urls = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();

        try {
            sleep(5000);
            Connection.Response connection = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .userAgent(networkSettings.getUserAgents().get(new Random().nextInt(6)).toString())
                    .referrer(networkSettings.getReferrer())
                    .timeout(networkSettings.getTimeout())
                    .followRedirects(false)
                    .execute();

             Document document = connection.parse();
            Elements elements = document.select("body").select("a");

            for (Element perElement : elements) {
                String link = perElement.absUrl("href");

                if (isLink(link) && !isFile(link)) {
                    urls.add(link);
                }
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e + "  " + url);

        }

        return urls;

    }

    private boolean isLink(String link) {

        return link.startsWith(site.getUrl());

    }

    private boolean isFile(String link) {

        return link.contains(".pdf")
                || link.contains(".png")
                || link.contains(".gif")
                || link.contains(".eps")
                || link.contains(".webp")
                || link.contains(".doc")
                || link.contains(".pptx")
                || link.contains("?_ga")
                || link.contains(".xlsx")
                || link.contains(".docx")
                || link.contains(".jpg")
                || link.contains("#");

    }

}
```

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class WebCrawler extends RecursiveAction {

    @Getter
    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Page> siteMapChildren =new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    private final NetworkSettings networkSettings;

    private PageRepository pageRepository;

    private SiteRepository siteRepository;
    private Site site;

    private final Page page;
    private final static CopyOnWriteArrayList <String> linksVisited = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();


    @Autowired
    public WebCrawler(NetworkSettings networkSettings,Page page,PageRepository pageRepository,Site site,SiteRepository siteRepository) {
        this.page=page;
        this.site=site;
        this.pageRepository=pageRepository;
        this.siteRepository=siteRepository;
        this.networkSettings =networkSettings;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {

        linksVisited.add(site.getUrl());

        HtmlParser htmlParser = new HtmlParser(networkSettings,site);

        siteRepository.save(site);

        ConcurrentSkipListSet<String> links = htmlParser.getUrls(site.getUrl());

        for (String perLink : links) {

            if (!linksVisited.contains(perLink)) {

                Page path = new Page();

                linksVisited.add(perLink);

                path.setPath(perLink.replace(site.getUrl(),""));

                addChildren(path);

                path.setSite(site);

                try {

                    sleep(5000);

                    Connection.Response connection = Jsoup.connect(perLink)

                            .ignoreContentType(true)

                            .userAgent(networkSettings.getUserAgents().get(new Random().nextInt(6)).toString())

                            .referrer(networkSettings.getReferrer())

                            .timeout(networkSettings.getTimeout())

                            .followRedirects(false)

                            .execute();

                    Document document = connection.parse();

                    String content=document.html();

                    path.setContent(content);

                    pageRepository.save(path);

                } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {

                    System.out.println(e + " " + perLink);

                }


            }

        }

        List<WebCrawler> mapOfSiteTasks = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Page child : getSiteMapChildren()) {

            WebCrawler webCrawlerTask = new WebCrawler(networkSettings,child,pageRepository,site,siteRepository);


            webCrawlerTask.fork();

            mapOfSiteTasks.add(webCrawlerTask);

        }

        for (WebCrawler perTask : mapOfSiteTasks) {

            perTask.join();

        }
    }
    public void addChildren(Page children)
    {
        siteMapChildren.add(children);
    }


}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class IndexServiceImp implements IndexService {

    private final NetworkSettings networkSettings;

    private final SitesList sitesList;

    private ScheduledExecutorService service;

    private final SiteRepository siteRepository;

    private final PageRepository pageRepository;


    @Override
    public IndexResponse startIndexing() {
       if (isIndexing()) {
              return new IndexResponse(false, "Index already started ");
       }
        Site site;
            for (SiteFromConf siteFromConf1 : sitesList.getSites()) {
                site = new Site();
                Page page = new Page();
                site.setName(siteFromConf1.getName());
                site.setUrl(siteFromConf1.getUrl().replace("www.", ""));
                LocalDateTime statusTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                site.setStatusTime(statusTime);
                site.setStatus(Status.INDEXING);
                page.setSite(site);
                WebCrawlerExecutor webCrawler = new WebCrawlerExecutor(networkSettings, page, pageRepository, site, siteRepository);
                service=Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                service.schedule(webCrawler,1000L,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
        return new IndexResponse(true, "");
    }


    @Override
    public IndexResponse stopIndexing() throws InterruptedException {

                List<Site> perSite = siteRepository.findAll();
                for (Site site : perSite) {
                    if (site.getStatus().equals(Status.INDEXING)) {
                        site.setStatus(Status.FAILED);
                        siteRepository.saveAndFlush(site);
                        log.info("Canceling task");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        service.shutdownNow();
                    }
                }
        return new IndexResponse(true, "");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isIndexing() {
        List<Site> site = siteRepository.findAll();
        for (Site siteUrlInfo : site) {
            if (siteUrlInfo.getStatus().equals(Status.INDEXING)) {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;

    }


}
```

I am solving a search engine indexing project in it I created a function that indexes the url(fetching data from a url and adds the data to the da tabase) while its processes I want to terminate the process using stopIndexing method with the help of TimerTask , but the issue is that the process continues and wont stop.

The result I got

```
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into page (code, content, path, site_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into page (code, content, path, site_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select site0_.id as id1_3_, site0_.last_error as last_err2_3_, site0_.name as name3_3_, site0_.status as status4_3_, site0_.status_time as status_t5_3_, site0_.url as url6_3_ from site site0_
Hibernate: update site set last_error=?, name=?, status=?, status_time=?, url=? where id=?
2024-02-05 15:55:26.557  INFO 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.implentations.IndexServiceImp        : Canceling task
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into page (code, content, path, site_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into page (code, content, path, site_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The result I expected

```
 Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into page (code, content, path, site_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into page (code, content, path, site_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select site0_.id as id1_3_, site0_.last_error as last_err2_3_, site0_.name as name3_3_, site0_.status as status4_3_, site0_.status_time as status_t5_3_, site0_.url as url6_3_ from site site0_
Hibernate: update site set last_error=?, name=?, status=?, status_time=?, url=? where id=?
2024-02-05 15:55:26.557  INFO 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.implentations.IndexServiceImp        : Canceling task

Process Terminated
```